# Calling a function after receiving value from Firebase request

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to get the response from a Firebase request like that?
So for example start a function once I have the children count value.

```
    let FAref = Firebase(url: "https://my-app.firebaseio.com/Users/\(uid!)/Data")


    FAref.observeEventType(FEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in


        if snapshot != nil {

            self.count = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)

        }


    }) { (error) -> Void in
        print(error.description)
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Once I get the             self.count = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)
 call a function

Comment: And what stops you from doing that? You can just call the function right after you set `self.count`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let FAref = Firebase(url: "https://my-app.firebaseio.com/Users/\(uid!)/Data")


    FAref.observeEventType(FEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in


        if snapshot != nil {

            let count = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)

            //Just add the function call after you get the childrenCount
            self.myFunction(count)
        }


    }) { (error) -> Void in
        print(error.description)
    }
```